# Error C2668: 'boost::bind' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, quantlib

I am trying to build Quantlib on VS2013 in the Release x64 mode.

I added the Boost libraries using Property Manager and then Went to solutions explorer and clicked on Build.

The final output was: Build: 18 succeeded, 1 failed. 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped.

When I double clicked on the error this file opened up (convolvedstudentt.cpp)

```
 Copyright (C) 2014 Jose Aparicio

 This file is part of QuantLib, a free-software/open-source library
 for financial quantitative analysts and developers - http://quantlib.org/

 QuantLib is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 under the terms of the QuantLib license.  You should have received a
 copy of the license along with this program; if not, please email
 <quantlib-dev@lists.sf.net>. The license is also available online at
 <http://quantlib.org/license.shtml>.

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the license for more details.
*/

#include <ql/experimental/math/convolvedstudentt.hpp>
#include <ql/errors.hpp>
#include <ql/math/factorial.hpp>
#include <ql/math/distributions/normaldistribution.hpp>
#include <ql/math/solvers1d/brent.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (((__GNUC__ == 4) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ >= 8)) || (__GNUC__ > 4))
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-local-typedefs"
#endif
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (((__GNUC__ == 4) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ >= 8)) || (__GNUC__ > 4))
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif

namespace QuantLib {

    CumulativeBehrensFisher::CumulativeBehrensFisher(
        const std::vector<Integer>& degreesFreedom,
        const std::vector<Real>& factors
        )
    : degreesFreedom_(degreesFreedom), factors_(factors),
      polyConvolved_(std::vector<Real>(1, 1.)), // value to start convolution
      a_(0.)
    {
        QL_REQUIRE(degreesFreedom.size() == factors.size(),
            "Incompatible sizes in convolution.");
        for(Size i=0; i<degreesFreedom.size(); i++) {
            QL_REQUIRE(degreesFreedom[i]%2 != 0,
                "Even degree of freedom not allowed");
            QL_REQUIRE(degreesFreedom[i] >= 0,
                "Negative degree of freedom not allowed");
        }
        for(Size i=0; i<degreesFreedom_.size(); i++)
            polynCharFnc_.push_back(polynCharactT((degreesFreedom[i]-1)/2));
        // adjust the polynomial coefficients by the factors in the linear
        //   combination:
        for(Size i=0; i<degreesFreedom_.size(); i++) {
            Real multiplier = 1.;
            for(Size k=1; k<polynCharFnc_[i].size(); k++) {
                multiplier *= std::abs(factors_[i]);
                polynCharFnc_[i][k] *= multiplier;
            }
        }
        //convolution, here it is a product of polynomials and exponentials
        for(Size i=0; i<polynCharFnc_.size(); i++)
            polyConvolved_ =
                convolveVectorPolynomials(polyConvolved_, polynCharFnc_[i]);
          // trim possible zeros that might have arised:
          std::vector<Real>::reverse_iterator it = polyConvolved_.rbegin();
          while(it != polyConvolved_.rend()) {
              if(*it == 0.) {
                polyConvolved_.pop_back();
                it = polyConvolved_.rbegin();
              }else{
                  break;
              }
          }
          // cache 'a' value (the exponent)
          for(Size i=0; i<degreesFreedom_.size(); i++)
              a_ += std::sqrt(static_cast<Real>(degreesFreedom_[i]))
                * std::abs(factors_[i]);
          a2_ = a_ * a_;
    }

    Disposable<std::vector<Real> >
    CumulativeBehrensFisher::polynCharactT(Natural n) const {
        Natural nu = 2 * n +1;
        std::vector<Real> low(1,1.), high(1,1.);
        high.push_back(std::sqrt(static_cast<Real>(nu)));
        if(n==0) return low;
        if(n==1) return high;

        for(Size k=1; k<n; k++) {
            std::vector<Real> recursionFactor(1,0.); // 0 coef
            recursionFactor.push_back(0.); // 1 coef
            recursionFactor.push_back(nu/((2.*k+1.)*(2.*k-1.))); // 2 coef
            std::vector<Real> lowUp =
                convolveVectorPolynomials(recursionFactor, low);
            //add them up:
            for(Size i=0; i<high.size(); i++)
                lowUp[i] += high[i];
            low = high;
            high = lowUp;
        }
        return high;
    }

    Disposable<std::vector<Real> >
    CumulativeBehrensFisher::convolveVectorPolynomials(
        const std::vector<Real>& v1,
        const std::vector<Real>& v2) const {
    #if defined(QL_EXTRA_SAFETY_CHECKS)
        QL_REQUIRE(!v1.empty() && !v2.empty(),
            "Incorrect vectors in polynomial.");
    #endif

        const std::vector<Real>& shorter = v1.size() < v2.size() ? v1 : v2;
        const std::vector<Real>& longer = (v1 == shorter) ? v2 : v1;

        Size newDegree = v1.size()+v2.size()-2;
        std::vector<Real> resultB(newDegree+1, 0.);
        for(Size polyOrdr=0; polyOrdr<resultB.size(); polyOrdr++) {
            for(Size i=std::max<Integer>(0, polyOrdr-longer.size()+1);
                i<=std::min(polyOrdr, shorter.size()-1); i++)
                resultB[polyOrdr] += shorter[i]*longer[polyOrdr-i];
        }
        return resultB;
    }

    Probability CumulativeBehrensFisher::operator()(const Real x) const {
        // 1st & 0th terms with the table integration
        Real integral = polyConvolved_[0] * std::atan(x/a_);
        Real squared = a2_ + x*x;
        Real rootsqr = std::sqrt(squared);
        Real atan2xa = std::atan2(-x,a_);
        if(polyConvolved_.size()>1)
            integral += polyConvolved_[1] * x/squared;

        for(Size exponent = 2; exponent <polyConvolved_.size(); exponent++) {
            integral -= polyConvolved_[exponent] *
                Factorial::get(exponent-1) * std::sin((exponent)*atan2xa)
                    /std::pow(rootsqr, static_cast<Real>(exponent));
         }
        return .5 + integral / M_PI;
    }

    Probability
    CumulativeBehrensFisher::density(const Real x) const {
        Real squared = a2_ + x*x;
        Real integral = polyConvolved_[0] * a_ / squared;
        Real rootsqr = std::sqrt(squared);
        Real atan2xa = std::atan2(-x,a_);
        for(Size exponent=1; exponent <polyConvolved_.size(); exponent++) {
            integral += polyConvolved_[exponent] *
                Factorial::get(exponent) * std::cos((exponent+1)*atan2xa)
                    /std::pow(rootsqr, static_cast<Real>(exponent+1) );
        }
        return integral / M_PI;
    }



    InverseCumulativeBehrensFisher::InverseCumulativeBehrensFisher(
        const std::vector<Integer>& degreesFreedom,
        const std::vector<Real>& factors,
        Real accuracy)
    : normSqr_(std::inner_product(factors.begin(), factors.end(),
        factors.begin(), 0.)),
      accuracy_(accuracy), distrib_(degreesFreedom, factors) { }

    Real InverseCumulativeBehrensFisher::operator()(const Probability q) const {
        Probability effectiveq;
        Real sign;
        // since the distrib is symmetric solve only on the right side:
        if(q==0.5) {
            return 0.;
        }else if(q < 0.5) {
            sign = -1.;
            effectiveq = 1.-q;
        }else{
            sign = 1.;
            effectiveq = q;
        }
        Real xMin =
            InverseCumulativeNormal::standard_value(effectiveq) * normSqr_;
        // inversion will fail at the Brent's bounds-check if this is not enough
        // (q is very close to 1.), in a bad combination fails around 1.-1.e-7
        Real xMax = 1.e6;
        return sign *
            Brent().solve(boost::bind(std::bind2nd(std::minus<Real>(),
            effectiveq), boost::bind<Real>(
                &CumulativeBehrensFisher::operator (),
                distrib_, _1)), accuracy_, (xMin+xMax)/2., xMin, xMax);
    }

}
```

The error seems to be in the third line from the bottom. That's the one that's highlighted.

```
        effectiveq), boost::bind<Real>(
            &CumulativeBehrensFisher::operator (),
            distrib_, _1)), accuracy_, (xMin+xMax)/2., xMin, xMax);
```

When I hover a mouse over it, it says

Error: more than one instance of overloaded function "boost::bind" matches the argument list: function template "boost_bi::bind_t " etc. Please see the attached screenshot

[image]

How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: You need to select the overload you want by casting to a pointer to a function of the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up quite a few times lately on the QuantLib mailing list. In short, the code worked with Boost 1.57 (the latest version at the time of the QuantLib 1.5 release) but broke with Boost 1.58.

There's a fix for this in the [QuantLib master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib), but it hasn't made it into a release yet. If you want to (or have to) use Boost 1.58, you can check out the latest code from there. If you want to use a released QuantLib version instead, the workaround is to downgrade to Boost 1.57.